# Unable to create spring-mvc project in STS

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a spring mvc project. I am creating a Maven project and then selecting the archetypes as

```
GroupId : co.ntier
ArtifactId : spring-mvc-archetype
Version: 1.0.2
```

I am getting this error:

```
Unable to create project from archetype [co.ntier:spring-mvc-archetype:1.0.2 -> http://maven-repository.com/artifact/co.ntier/spring-mvc-archetype/1.0.2]
The defined artifact is not an archetype
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try cleaning up your .m2\repository\ folder. Don't forget to set your proxy in settings.xml. settings.xml is manually created therefore you need to make your own and set the proxy. Here's a sample template for setting up your proxy inside settings.xml

```html
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host> --your proxy here-- </host>
      <port> --your port no here-- </port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

When you make a new Maven Project and add a new archetype, use this Repository URL instead: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

By the way I'm using Eclipse Luna and it works on my end.

Comment: @Arya Great to hear that. :) I tried searching from the web before about this issue but the answers most of the time were vague. I did some experimentation, and finally I got it, I would be happy to share my solution.

Comment: where is settings.xml ?

Comment: @TamimAdDari basically it's a configuration file. When you install your maven, .m2 folder is created. Usually it is in this directory, C:\Users\<Your computer username>\.m2 

settings.xml is not included by default, you have to create it manually in the root directory of .m2 folder.

\.m2\settings.xml

Comment: You said to clean up the repository folder, what exactly do you mean by clean up? Just add the settings.xml?

Comment: @Question_Guy clean up means, whatever files you see in your /repository folder, just delete it and let maven generate it again (sometimes it's automatic when you make a new project, if it doesn't generate the files you can: Right-click to your project in eclipse, select Maven -> Update Project.. -> check the "Force Update from Snapshots/Releases"  ). Then add your settings.xml.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have only change repository URL. try with this url:http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Answer (score 0):

Try by   deleting  /co folder inside m2/repository and  then add a new archytype while creating Eclipse project. .  use this  for Repository URL :http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/